# SweetAlert jQuery not working in success callback

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

I can't get any jQuery to work when using [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/).

In the fiddle below I want to hide the box div on success.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
function confirmDelete() {
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
}, function (isConfirm) {
    if (!isConfirm) return;
    $.ajax({
        url: "scriptDelete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: 5
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function () {
            swal("Done!", "It was succesfully deleted!", "success");
            $('#box').hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
        }
    });
});
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4epb896/)

Comment: did you check browser console? any error ? let us know

Comment: Yep, getting `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. Only happens when I add the `$('#box').hide();` code.

Comment: change `dataType: "html",` to `dataType: "json",`

Comment: Error is gone, div still not hiding? This is mental!

Comment: Does SWAL disable regular jQuery actions?

Comment: Are you getting this alert:-swal("Done!", "It was succesfully deleted!", "success");

Comment: Yes swal is working fine, I just can't manipulate the dom in any way on the success callback.

Comment: Are you aware that the reason the box isn't hiding because the swal is going into the error block on confirmDelete()?

Comment: until i will see your html, i can't comment.Add it in your question

Comment: @j9070749 that was the problem. I'm actually using my own code in my set up, used this fiddle to demonstrate the problem, didn't realise it was forcing the error on the first function. That was the issue, but I still can't get it working locally. May have to post up my code instead.

Comment: I'm doing it differently using then and if. As I couldn't get it working on either I assumed it was an issue with SweetAlert, obviously not though. Will have to dig a bit deeper into my own code.

Comment: @spice glad I could help.

Comment: @spice Please update your question with the details that you've commented.  Please also provide any other relevant details to your question -- this will help future researchers to understand if their issue is the same issue as yours.  When complete, please summon me back so that I can neutralize the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because of the invalid URL on the first JS function and it was going into the error block and not actually calling the hide function within the success block.